# Which headers should an automatically generated email include?

Tags: php, email

There are a few mail headers that have obvious practical reasons to be included (for example `From:` and `Reply-To:`). Then there are headers like `MIME-Version:` and `Message-ID:` which seem optional.

Assuming the number of lines of code isn't an issue, what headers should an automatically generated email ideally include? For instance, are there headers which are optional, but including them could prevent getting incorrectly flagged as spam?

Comment: In the current situation, I'm sending the emails with PHP, but I feel the question could fit just as well for whichever method is being used to send the mail.

Comment: Several anti-spam requires your emails to have a link where the user can blacklist his email from your site, as well as it having to come from the originating domain.

Comment: @MrJack Since most personal email doesn't have such a link, that doesn't seem like a general requirement.

Comment: I think most email APIs will automatically include all the headers that are required by the protocol. Spam filtering is mostly based on message contents and IP blacklists/whitelists, not adding random header fields.

Comment: @Barmar Most commercial emails do, so the volume sent has something to do with it. Asking google directly might work too.

Comment: Yes, commercial email should. But there's no way to tell that an email is commercial email. And of course, it only makes sense if the user is on a list that they can request removal from. It wouldn't make sense in a registration conformation email, for instance.